# C# / How to remove old data from a stream

Tags: c#, android

Fellows,

I'm using the code below to receive data from a bluetooth device, the usefull information ends as soon as an 'F' comes, then the '\r' and '\n' are received.

The issue is that, the when the program starts to receive data again, the first two bytes are '\r' and '\n'.

I've tried to dispose(), close() and flush(), but the string delimiters (\r and \n) are still there when the code reaches the wile loop again.
   I just need to remove old data before receiving new bytes.

```
int i1 = 0;
while (true)
{
    datum[i1] = await Task.Run(() => (byte)InmStream.ReadByte());
    int datum_check = datum[i1];
    if (datum_check == 70) // F (char) = 70  
        {
            datum[i1] = Convert.ToByte(10); // replaces the F by '\n'
            break;
        }
        i1++;
}
```

The first 7 bytes, datum[0] until datum[6], received in the first time the code runs are: 3, \r, \n, 3, 5, \r and \n.

The 7 bytes received in the second run and on are: \r, \n, 3, \r, \n, 3, 5...

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

It's worth mentioning that my background is from a totally different area.

Comment: Maybe those bytes are still sitting in the bluetooth device's hardware buffer.  It would explain why closing or flushing the stream isn't having an effect.

Comment: @RJM Indeed, at first it seems that it should be related to hardware. The thing is if I use a hyper terminal on my smartphone to receive the info, the data is correctly displayed everytime.

Thanks anyway.